# Virtuemart Display Page after Remote redirect

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I am aiming to create a payment module.  Its users shall be redirected away from the site's URL in order for the transaction to be processed by a third party at a different URL.  I would then like customers to be redirected back to a generic 'success' page that notifies them the order was a success.  I have tried redirecting to the default success page (checkout.thankyou.php), but I get lots of errors; all the constants etc. that the application requires have obviously been lost during the redirect.

I would like to be able to retrieve the theme currently enabled in the configuration and use it to insert some basic HTML into the view.  I would also like to access the database to perform some queries.

Can anybody advise?  I am very stuck, and cannot find anything useful in the documentation!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific about what type of information you want in your success page? If you just want basic HTML, then there's no reason you can't just write a basic Joomla article and redirect to that instead of trying to redirect to a VM partial. Again, if it's just basic HTML (no data from the transaction), then you can simply use a code inspector (like FireFox Inspect Element) to track down the CSS classes you like from the template and simply use them in your Joomla article to make it look like the VM template. You can find most of them in `components/com_virtuemart/themes/default/themes.css`.

If you need to display actual transaction data in your Thank You message, be prepared for a bit more work. You're probably going to have to write a cookie containing the record data BEFORE it gets sent offsite, and then read the cookie just prior to rendering the Thank You page.